# Count lowest number of lines among list of files

Tags: bash

I want to print count for file with lowest number of lines among the list of files. Nothing is printed.

Here is the code

```
MINcount=$(for txtfile in /home/folder/*.txt;
      do
          LC=$(cat $txtfile | wc -l);
           min=0
          (($LC < min || min == 0)) && min=$LC
      done)
 echo $MINcount
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following pipe:

```
wc -l /home/folder/*.txt | sort -n | head -n1 | cut -f1
```

Explanation

`wc -l /home/folder/*.txt | sort -n` will produce output like this:

```
  50 file2
  94 file1
 144 total
```

`wc` prints the total in the first line, and then the lines per file, which get sorted in numerical order (`sort -n`). `head -n1` will then select the first line from output, `cut -f1` the first column from that line.

Comment: Thus you shouldn't use the `-r` otherwise it will return the largest line count ;)

Comment: @Ploutox Oh, then I misread the question. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 3):

give this a try:

```
 wc -l /home/folder/*.txt|sort -n|awk '{print $1;exit}'
```

Comment: Why not simply write `print $1` instead of `$0=$1;print` ?